# Python 3 Input to 2D List

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, input, 2d

I'm trying to get input of 3 numbers, then save them into a 2-D list.

ex.

```
Input: 1 2 3
Input: 4 5 6
Input: 7 8 9

= [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

When I try to add the inputs to a list I get this:

```
['1 2 3', '4 5 6', '7 8 9']
```

```
myList=[]
in=input("3 numbers:")
myList.append(in)

while in!= "":
    in=input("Enter 3 numbers: ")
    in.split()
    myList.append(in)
```

I need them to be integers too so I can do maths with them later but I have no idea how to do that and save the inputs to a 2d list at the same time.

Comment: are you sure `in` is a legal variable name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little extension on Eric's answer, since you also asked for `int`s.

```
nos = list(int(x) for x in nos.split())
```

Note that I renamed the input to `nos`, because `in` is a reserved Python keyword - and I even just used it here. Never a good idea to name variables the same as keywords. An alternative version:

```
nos = nos.split()
for x in nos:
    x = int(x)
```

The first line is the same as Eric's, but I loop through the list and convert each value to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Split doesn't modify the original

```
in = in.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright so for some reason both of these guys are giving you some weird manner of doing this, not too sure why not just instantiate a 2d array, and go from there. ie

```
imp = [[] for x in range(3)] #Instantiate it
for i in range(3):
    for k in range(3):
        imp[i].extend([int(input("Value at["+str(i)+"]["+str(k)+"]:"))]) #Input your own values
print(imp)#Display the array.
```

This is the best direct manner for doing it. It's possible to do the whole thing with list comprehension, but not too sure if that would confuse you a bit more than I want to.

Edit:
The main point that this goes forwards with is giving you the index that you are inputting into the given list as well.